# Python regular expression to match a file name. Using os.walk() to get a file name

Tags: python, regex

I'm using os.walk() to get files name. What I need to do is to create a list with files name that match following patterns:

if `'*'` will match all files.

if `'h*'` will match all files beginning with h.

if `'*h'` will match all files ending with h.

if `'*h*'` will match all files that have h in them.

if `[h-w]*` will match any one character in set, including set negation [^h-w]

I'm new with regular expression and I have troubles with creating an if statement for this issue. May some explain it to me (maybe with code examples) how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: `*` is not a valid regex. Maybe you want a `fnmatch`-type pattern?

Comment: Also, the regex `h*` matches files named `h`, `hh`, `hhh`, etc., but not files others. The **pattern** `h*` matches filenames starting with `h`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, no -- this is clearly conflating regular expressions with fnmatch-style patterns. `*h` isn't a valid regex either -- the `*` character has to have something else preceding it, as it modifies the prior token to be 0-or-more.

Comment: as an alternative to `os.walk`/`fnmatch.filter`, [`pathlib` supports recursive globbing.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)

Answer (score 1):

I tried `fnmatch`, and it's working perfectly, a Big Thanks to [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy).
Here is my code:

```
for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for ff in filenames:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(ff, 'My patterns here'):
             list.append(os.path.join(dp, ff))
```

Comment: you could use `matching_files = [os.path.join(root, fn) for fn in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '[h-w]*')]`. Or replace `list.append` with `yield`.